# pc becomes slow when launching windows xp mode in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

I have 2gb ram, 250GB hdd, and a  pentium dual core with 2.50Ghz.
I don't know why but everytime I launch the windows xp mode which only consumes 256Mb of ram(indicated in the settings). Makes my computer slow. And I only have google chrome launched.
What do I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my limited knowledge on the subject, windows xp mode is based on hardware virtulization, which means that as soon as you switch on xp-mode you processor starts to run 2 operating systems at a time. So, what you need to be looking at is the cpu usage which should skyrocket when you turn it on.

Comment: How do I change the settings to use only minimal processor power

Answer (score 1):

Through Windows XP Mode Settings improve RAM allocation from 512 MB to 1024 or more to get the improved performance & speed.

To do this you need to change Close settings to Shut Down for XP mode, then while windows XP Mode is Shut Down you can edit settings.